An infinite page has squares of size x*x. What is the possibility of a coin covering the vertex when thrown?
I am trying to write a puzzle. I was playing around with flipping a coin on a piece of paper with a square design. Sometimes I landed on the vertices, sometimes not. I tried to calculate the probability as a self-motivated challenge. I started with 2 versions and am not sure about how to get a solution for either.

An infinite page  has squares of size x*x. What is the possibility of a coin covering the vertex when thrown?

case (a)  the coin being of radius 1 and square of size 2 by 2
case (b) the coin is of radius 1 and square of size sqrt3 by sqrt3


I have the general logic down on how to solve it. I can have the coin center either distance 0 from the vertex, or max distance 1, the radius from the center. The only cases for which the coin won't cover the vertex is when the center is not distance one. The center could be at a distance between sqrt2 and 1 for case a
What would you suggest to do to solve? When I did a simulation I got

 pi/4 for a and around 0.92 for b


@lodo Could you tell us more about the puzzle you're trying to write?

@GarethMcCaughan i was just playing around with a coin and flipping it on a piece of paper that has a square design and  while flipping i sometimes landed on the vertices some times not and then i tried to solve this on a piece  of paper playing around with the square size , i just choose numbers that seemed vague in guessing the probability compared to a larger or lower sizes of squares , it is more of a self motivated challenge not sure where to go building the puzzle from here since as i keep the coin size constant the  extreme sizes for the square seem to be too clear

You can't define a uniform distribution on $\mathbb R^2$ so the definition of probability should be stated as a limit or density.

@Lucenaposition can you elaborate  on why is that the case?

It means each 1x1 square must have 0 or positive probability, but if the probability is 0 then the probability of it being somewhere is 0 and if the probability is >0 the probability of being somewhere is infinite.

thank you helped alot

Case (a):

 The center must be outside the dark red area:  

Case (b):

 


i have a question regarding number a i drew it in the same sense got pi/4 yet i got confused regarding the correctness  when i made the center of the circle   at    distance 1 from the vertex  in a diagonal  line and i started to feel like i am missing  some possible solutions

after writing a code i got the similar answers for the first it seems like i am missing some intuition why changing the center won’t cause overlapping solutions for the first

I agree with your first part. The second part calculates as 1.963418 which is > 1. The diagonal of a √3 square is about 2.45, greater than the coin's diameter. I get 0.926419.

So that's $3 \times \sqrt{3}$, not $ \sqrt[3]{3}$, which is what the result looks like? No, I didn't ask Wolfram, I wrote the (originally faulty) code myself, in the spirit of this site.

Fixed the second image.
